# No existing Kibana index found . Unable to connect to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, vue.js, docker-compose, kibana-5

I am installing vue-storefront-api and vue-storefront on my windows machine. While running docker-compose up in windows power shell or command prompt, I am getting the error stating No existing Kibana index found","prevState":"red","prevMsg":"Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://es1:9200."}.

In kibana management , index pattern configuration  logstash-* index pattern doesn't match any index pattern and it is showing the error.
"Unable to fetch mapping. Do you have indices matching the pattern?".

```js
//docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  es1:
    image: elasticsearch:5.5
    container_name: es1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    mem_limit: 1g
    volumes:
      - esdat1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet
  es2:
    image: elasticsearch:5.5
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=es1"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    mem_limit: 1g
    volumes:
      - esdat2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet

  kibana:
    image: kibana:5.5
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://es1:9200
    networks:
        - esnet

  redis:  
    image: redis

    ports:
      - "6379:6379"      


volumes:
  esdat1:
    driver: local
  esdat2:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

Here is the log after running docker-compose up.

es1       | [2018-06-21T06:44:15,059][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [rkkxMa-] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
es1       | [2018-06-21T06:44:15,060][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [rkkxMa-] loaded module [ingest-common]
es1       | [2018-06-21T06:44:15,060][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [rkkxMa-] loaded module [lang-expression]
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:15Z","tags":["status","plugin:kibana@5.5.2","info"],"pid":9,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:15Z","tags":["status","plugin:elasticsearch@5.5.2","info"],"pid":9,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:15Z","tags":["status","plugin:console@5.5.2","info"],"pid":9,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:15Z","tags":["status","plugin:metrics@5.5.2","info"],"pid":9,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:15Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":9,"message":"Request error, retrying\nHEAD http://es1:9200/ => connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.3:9200"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:16Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":9,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://es1:9200/"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:16Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":9,"message":"No living connections"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:16Z","tags":["status","plugin:timelion@5.5.2","info"],"pid":9,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:16Z","tags":["status","plugin:elasticsearch@5.5.2","error"],"pid":9,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from yellow to red - Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://es1:9200.","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"Waiting for Elasticsearch"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:16Z","tags":["listening","info"],"pid":9,"message":"Server running at http://0.0.0.0:5601"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:16Z","tags":["status","ui settings","error"],"pid":9,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to red - Elasticsearch plugin is red","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:18Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":9,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://es1:9200/"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:18Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":9,"message":"No living connections"}
es1       | [2018-06-21T06:44:18,954][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [rkkxMa-] using discovery type [zen]
es2_1     | [2018-06-21T06:44:18,985][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [LUIwP6v] using discovery type [zen]
es1       | [2018-06-21T06:44:19,988][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] initialized
es1       | [2018-06-21T06:44:19,988][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [rkkxMa-] starting ...
es2_1     | [2018-06-21T06:44:20,039][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] initialized
es2_1     | [2018-06-21T06:44:20,040][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [LUIwP6v] starting ...
es2_1     | [2018-06-21T06:44:20,271][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [LUIwP6v] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}
es1       | [2018-06-21T06:44:20,311][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [rkkxMa-] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:21Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":9,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://es1:9200/"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:21Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":9,"message":"No living connections"}
es1       | [2018-06-21T06:44:23,418][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [rkkxMa-] new_master {rkkxMa-}{rkkxMa-aSw6l9XemwtNUtQ}{k16a3-7gSmWF-kgsBXG59Q}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)
es2_1     | [2018-06-21T06:44:23,411][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [LUIwP6v] new_master {LUIwP6v}{LUIwP6vfQs2yrECMbU67ug}{4cXpbDorQU-bUcDr-k-h-w}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)
es1       | [2018-06-21T06:44:23,477][INFO ][o.e.h.n.Netty4HttpServerTransport] [rkkxMa-] publish_address {172.18.0.3:9200}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9200}
es1       | [2018-06-21T06:44:23,477][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [rkkxMa-] started
es2_1     | [2018-06-21T06:44:23,485][INFO ][o.e.h.n.Netty4HttpServerTransport] [LUIwP6v] publish_address {172.18.0.2:9200}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9200}
es2_1     | [2018-06-21T06:44:23,492][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [LUIwP6v] started
es2_1     | [2018-06-21T06:44:23,495][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [LUIwP6v] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
es1       | [2018-06-21T06:44:23,695][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [rkkxMa-] recovered [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGJav.png) indices into cluster_state
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:24Z","tags":["status","plugin:elasticsearch@5.5.2","error"],"pid":9,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from red to red - Elasticsearch is still initializing the kibana index.","prevState":"red","prevMsg":"Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://es1:9200."}
es1       | [2018-06-21T06:44:24,255][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [rkkxMa-] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[vue_storefront_catalog][4]] ...]).
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:26Z","tags":["status","plugin:elasticsearch@5.5.2","info"],"pid":9,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from red to green - Kibana index ready","prevState":"red","prevMsg":"Elasticsearch is still initializing the kibana index."}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:26Z","tags":["status","ui settings","info"],"pid":9,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from red to green - Ready","prevState":"red","prevMsg":"Elasticsearch plugin is red"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:33Z","tags":[],"pid":9,"method":"get","statusCode":200,"req":{"url":"/app/kibana","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","cache-control":"max-age=0","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36","accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":200,"responseTime":245,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /app/kibana 200 245ms - 9.0B"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:34Z","tags":[],"pid":9,"method":"get","statusCode":304,"req":{"url":"/ui/fonts/open_sans/open_sans_v13_latin_300.woff2","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","origin":"http://localhost:5601","if-none-match":"\"2da4d6d1b1bef32c05719680145b61613b3829b4\"","if-modified-since":"Mon, 14 Aug 2017 12:44:50 GMT","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36","accept":"*/*","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":304,"responseTime":22,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /ui/fonts/open_sans/open_sans_v13_latin_300.woff2 304 22ms - 9.0B"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:34Z","tags":[],"pid":9,"method":"get","statusCode":304,"req":{"url":"/bundles/kibana.style.css?v=15443","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36","accept":"text/css,*/*;q=0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9","if-none-match":"\"6ce3d5c4c04abd68e56a434a3e7d818b6966cac6-gzip\"","if-modified-since":"Mon, 14 Aug 2017 12:44:50 GMT"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":304,"responseTime":19,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /bundles/kibana.style.css?v=15443 304 19ms - 9.0B"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:34Z","tags":[],"pid":9,"method":"get","statusCode":304,"req":{"url":"/bundles/commons.style.css?v=15443","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36","accept":"text/css,*/*;q=0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9","if-none-match":"\"1ee3af1c283854e8fba7c7e2f983ec98e335e515-gzip\"","if-modified-since":"Mon, 14 Aug 2017 12:44:50 GMT"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":304,"responseTime":32,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /bundles/commons.style.css?v=15443 304 32ms - 9.0B"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:34Z","tags":[],"pid":9,"method":"get","statusCode":200,"req":{"url":"/ui/favicons/favicon-32x32.png","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","pragma":"no-cache","cache-control":"no-cache","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36","accept":"image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":200,"responseTime":18,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /ui/favicons/favicon-32x32.png 200 18ms - 9.0B"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:34Z","tags":[],"pid":9,"method":"get","statusCode":304,"req":{"url":"/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=15443","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36","accept":"*/*","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9","if-none-match":"\"7fa86ba60914a3bbce4c44d06d095887b53fcb1f-gzip\"","if-modified-since":"Mon, 14 Aug 2017 12:44:50 GMT"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":304,"responseTime":58,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=15443 304 58ms - 9.0B"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:34Z","tags":[],"pid":9,"method":"get","statusCode":304,"req":{"url":"/ui/favicons/favicon-16x16.png","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36","accept":"image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9","if-none-match":"\"f33f077bfe13045136046c93b6180be0379386ff\"","if-modified-since":"Mon, 14 Aug 2017 12:44:50 GMT"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":304,"responseTime":5,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /ui/favicons/favicon-16x16.png 304 5ms - 9.0B"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:34Z","tags":[],"pid":9,"method":"get","statusCode":304,"req":{"url":"/ui/favicons/favicon.ico","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36","accept":"image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9","if-none-match":"\"72df422636eb8c15a5f38607b794cb22f67f6dc5-gzip\"","if-modified-since":"Mon, 14 Aug 2017 12:44:50 GMT"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":304,"responseTime":5,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /ui/favicons/favicon.ico 304 5ms - 9.0B"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:34Z","tags":[],"pid":9,"method":"get","statusCode":304,"req":{"url":"/bundles/kibana.bundle.js?v=15443","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36","accept":"*/*","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9","if-none-match":"\"e9ece38643514f9717af281c78d118aaccd7fc47-gzip\"","if-modified-since":"Mon, 14 Aug 2017 12:44:50 GMT"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":304,"responseTime":146,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /bundles/kibana.bundle.js?v=15443 304 146ms - 9.0B"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:34Z","tags":[],"pid":9,"method":"get","statusCode":200,"req":{"url":"/api/console/api_server?sense_version=%40%40SENSE_VERSION&apis=es_5_0","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","accept":"application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01","x-requested-with":"XMLHttpRequest","kbn-version":"5.5.2","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":200,"responseTime":32,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /api/console/api_server?sense_version=%40%40SENSE_VERSION&apis=es_5_0 200 32ms - 9.0B"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:34Z","tags":[],"pid":9,"method":"get","statusCode":304,"req":{"url":"/plugins/kibana/assets/discover.svg","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","if-none-match":"\"c4035451a8e776d0f0cd354a825ec432ad06884e-gzip\"","if-modified-since":"Mon, 14 Aug 2017 12:44:50 GMT","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36","accept":"image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":304,"responseTime":8,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /plugins/kibana/assets/discover.svg 304 8ms - 9.0B"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:34Z","tags":[],"pid":9,"method":"get","statusCode":304,"req":{"url":"/plugins/kibana/assets/visualize.svg","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","if-none-match":"\"4cc79a4d91bd0380d0c82a6b092f339d185670ef-gzip\"","if-modified-since":"Mon, 14 Aug 2017 12:44:50 GMT","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36","accept":"image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":304,"responseTime":8,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /plugins/kibana/assets/visualize.svg 304 8ms - 9.0B"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:34Z","tags":[],"pid":9,"method":"get","statusCode":304,"req":{"url":"/plugins/kibana/assets/dashboard.svg","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","if-none-match":"\"42c2161fa64691414784868afdd722444460763a-gzip\"","if-modified-since":"Mon, 14 Aug 2017 12:44:50 GMT","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36","accept":"image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":304,"responseTime":10,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /plugins/kibana/assets/dashboard.svg 304 10ms - 9.0B"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:34Z","tags":[],"pid":9,"method":"get","statusCode":304,"req":{"url":"/plugins/kibana/assets/wrench.svg","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","if-none-match":"\"088a9a98c99e406dca2354af14f688ad84826b97-gzip\"","if-modified-since":"Mon, 14 Aug 2017 12:44:50 GMT","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36","accept":"image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":304,"responseTime":8,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /plugins/kibana/assets/wrench.svg 304 8ms - 9.0B"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:34Z","tags":[],"pid":9,"method":"get","statusCode":304,"req":{"url":"/plugins/timelion/icon.svg","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","if-none-match":"\"cb793d5314d680b7d5ce130f0393a70b51989541-gzip\"","if-modified-since":"Mon, 14 Aug 2017 12:44:50 GMT","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36","accept":"image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":304,"responseTime":18,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /plugins/timelion/icon.svg 304 18ms - 9.0B"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:34Z","tags":[],"pid":9,"method":"get","statusCode":304,"req":{"url":"/plugins/kibana/assets/settings.svg","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","if-none-match":"\"4f859e27d4917026ff1590805887902b14ce79d5-gzip\"","if-modified-since":"Mon, 14 Aug 2017 12:44:50 GMT","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36","accept":"image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":304,"responseTime":11,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /plugins/kibana/assets/settings.svg 304 11ms - 9.0B"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:34Z","tags":[],"pid":9,"method":"get","statusCode":304,"req":{"url":"/plugins/kibana/assets/play-circle.svg","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","if-none-match":"\"2433ecf38258f7121c835670b6993600e7657717-gzip\"","if-modified-since":"Mon, 14 Aug 2017 12:44:50 GMT","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36","accept":"image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":304,"responseTime":12,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /plugins/kibana/assets/play-circle.svg 304 12ms - 9.0B"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:34Z","tags":[],"pid":9,"method":"get","statusCode":304,"req":{"url":"/bundles/0cebf3d61338c454670b1c5bdf5d6d8d.svg","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","if-none-match":"\"d52234e52fd4e96d20f52f4c03c0cedb8ab5fe17-gzip\"","if-modified-since":"Mon, 14 Aug 2017 12:44:50 GMT","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36","accept":"image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8","referer":"http://localhost:5601/bundles/commons.style.css?v=15443","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/bundles/commons.style.css?v=15443"},"res":{"statusCode":304,"responseTime":12,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /bundles/0cebf3d61338c454670b1c5bdf5d6d8d.svg 304 12ms - 9.0B"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:35Z","tags":[],"pid":9,"method":"get","statusCode":304,"req":{"url":"/ui/fonts/open_sans/open_sans_v13_latin_regular.woff2","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","origin":"http://localhost:5601","if-none-match":"\"afc44700053c9a28f9ab26f6aec4862ac1d0795d\"","if-modified-since":"Mon, 14 Aug 2017 12:44:50 GMT","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36","accept":"*/*","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":304,"responseTime":13,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /ui/fonts/open_sans/open_sans_v13_latin_regular.woff2 304 13ms - 9.0B"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"response","@timestamp":"2018-06-21T06:44:35Z","tags":[],"pid":9,"method":"get","statusCode":404,"req":{"url":"/api/index_patterns/_fields_for_wildcard?pattern=logstash-*&meta_fields=_source&meta_fields=_id&meta_fields=_type&meta_fields=_index&meta_fields=_score","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","kbn-version":"5.5.2","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":404,"responseTime":8,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /api/index_patterns/_fields_for_wildcard?pattern=logstash-*&meta_fields=_source&meta_fields=_id&meta_fields=_type&meta_fields=_index&meta_fields=_score 404 8ms - 9.0B"}
[image]

[image]

Screenshot of kibana dashboard

Comment: The issue is that ES is not reachable it seems. Can you also add your docker compose configuration?

Comment: @Val    I have added my docker configuartion screenshot. Please have a look at it

Comment: this is not what I asked for. I need to see the docker-compose.yml file

Comment: @val I have also added docker-compose.yml code snippet. Please check.

Comment: To me the networks section is missing `driver: bridge` at the end

Comment: My docker-compose.yml is the same as I posted here. Please suggest what I should write in the missing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to fix the network section like this:

```
networks:
  esnet:
    driver: bridge            <-- this line is missing
```

Comment: After fixing network section I am getting this

Expected a boolean [true/false] for property [has_options] but got [0]
[INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [rkkxMa-] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
 Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[vue_storefront_catalog][4]]

Comment: Yellow cluster means it should be up and reachable.